# Signout option not available to visitors

Tags: 2013, intranet

I have an intranet SharePoint site. When a visitor logs in which has only READ access on site, clicking on his name on top doesn't show "SIGNOUT" option.
But when some other user for e.g. contributor, administrator, owner etc. logs in then SIGNOUT option is visible.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on the security setting in Internet Explorer. Go to Internet Options > Security Tab. Select the *Local Intranet* zone, and click Sites. Uncheck the check-box *Automatically detect intranet network" option.

[image]

Close the browser, open it again and sign in. See if the Sign out option is present.